# Windows Phone: how to make a Call without permisson from user

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I need to develop an application which has to make scheduled calls. The problem is it must call without permisson from the user. Also, it must end the call after sometime. Therefore I can't use `PhoneCallTask`. I heard about `Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended.dll` and `Microsoft.Phone.InteropServices.dll` to use more features of the phone.

I downloaded them but I could not add them as reference to the project in visual studio. It says

> *A referance to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project.*

My question is that is there any way to implement such functionality (*call without permission and end call without any interaction with user.*)?

Solution can be for windows phone 7.1 or windows phone 8.

Good news is I will not upload it to the store... Therefore, I do not need it to be certified. Thanks...

Comment: I hope not. I wouldn't let your app anywhere near my phone.

Comment: Are you kidding? What user will allow such a thing on their own phone?

Comment: I would be surprised if you could! This would be a huge security flaw as it would allow your app to dial premium rate numbers and rack up a huge bill while making you very rich!

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible

Comment: It's easier to be honest than to install covert software on your bf/gf's phone, no?

Answer (score 9):

This is simply not possible, and that for a good reason. No matter what good reason you might think you have, this is not a proper way to achieve it. Also the interop assemblies, that indeed allow more functionality for certified partners, still does not provide such a functionality.

What do you think where this would lead to? It would lead to programs, silently calling very expensive numbers.